# How to check if URLs match, within a huge database of online products?

Tags: url, mongodb, preg-match, string-matching

So, the problem seems simple at the beginning but is not. Using Mongo and Node.js.

**Problem:** I have a URL. I need to match that URL with all the URLs I have in my database. **Remember**, there is no rule that the URL I'm on always have "category" infront or things like that. And please don't take "cases" into consideration.

I have no clue of the name of parameters, or anything else.

1. Let's assume the URL is smth like **example.com/category/product_name.html?session_id=2423412fd**

   In the database I only have **example.com/product_name.html**
2. The URL is smth like **example.com/index.php?productid=6&category=3&utm_campaign=google&utm_source=click**

   In the database I only have **example.com/index.php?productid=6**
3. The URL is smth like **example.com/product_name.html**

   In the database I only have **example.com/category/subcategory/product.html**

I think I made my point. What I'm looking is a solution that matches URL in any cases (they are more than these). It can be an external services, class or something complex.

But I need it to work, and to work very fast because is doing this on every page refresh.

Thank you!

Comment: In example 3, wouldn't those two URL's be different because of the path?

Comment: @Anagio, the technique in example 3 is very common in SEO, but essentially it's the same page behind different looking urls.

Comment: @alexandru.topliceanu thats bad to user underscores for SEO, see here http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/

Answer (score 0):

I would use this function to separate the strings http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Then take parts of the path name which you want to match from the URL and query your database URL's looking for matches.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from Anagio's answer, the URL

```
example.com/index.php?productid=6&category=3&utm_campaign=google&utm_source=click
```

could be saved as a Mongo object like:

```
{
  url: "example.com/index.php?productid=6&category=3&utm_campaign=google&utm_source=click",
  indexes: [
    "example.com",
    "index.php",
    "productid=6",
    "category=3",
    "utm_campaign=google",
    "utm_source=click"
  ]
}
```

You could then split up any new URL using the same algorithm, then do a map/reduce on the indexes field for scoring and then take the highest score as the best "fuzzy match"

Comment: this solution could be interesting. I wonder if it really works on any case. How fast would be to do this for every page load?

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell can you give an example of the map and reduce functions you would use for such a case. Their implementation is essential to obtaining the "fuzzy match" you were talking about